# Using FINDSTR to locate a string using regex

Tags: findstr

Hello I am trying to match lines in a text file using this:

```
findstr /i "6.0.0.0.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] Wave Embedded 6.0 ([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])" C:\IOManifest.txt
```

but all it does is open up the file at C:\IOManifest.txt and print it to screen...

a correct match would be "6.0.0.0.3456 Wave Embedded 6.0 (3957)

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Not using `findstr /?` to see what it does (and doesn't) support?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
echo 6.0.0.0.3456 Wave Embedded 6.0 (3957) | findstr /i "6.0.0.0.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] Wave Embedded 6.0 ([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])"
```

So you should use:

```
type C:\IOManifest.txt | findstr /i "6.0.0.0.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] Wave Embedded 6.0 ([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])"
```

Comment: crap, does that return any error level? because my previous script i was expecting an error level, then go through an if/else statement, maybe i was expecting a return that findstr isn't giving.